# A formula in Ramanujan's lost notebook and its connection with Chudnovsky series for $1/\pi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, ramanujan

While studying Berndt's *Ramanujan's Lost Notebook Vol. 2*, page 369 ([chapter on Springerlink](https://doi.org/10.1007/b13290_16)), I found that Ramanujan gave values of a certain expression $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{Q_n}}\left(\sqrt {n} P_n-\frac{6}{\pi}\right)\tag{1}$$ for a few integer values of $n$. Most notable among them is the value for $n=163$ with $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{Q_n}}\left(\sqrt {n} P_n-\frac{6}{\pi}\right)=362\sqrt{\frac{3}{3335}}\tag{2}$$ Let's now define the symbols used above to get full context needed for the question. We have by definition
\begin{align}
P(q) & =1-24\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{jq^j} {1-q^j}\tag{3a}\\
Q(q) & =1+240\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{j^3q^j} {1-q^j}\tag{3b}\\
R(q) & =1-504\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{j^5q^j} {1-q^j}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
and $$P_n=P(-e^{-\pi\sqrt {n}}), Q_n=Q(-e^{-\pi\sqrt {n}}), R_n=R(-e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}})\tag{4}$$ These expressions famously appear in the general series for $1/\pi$ given by Chudnovsky brothers $$ \frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-j_{n}}}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(6m)!}{(3m)!(m!)^{3}}\frac{a_{n} + mb_{n}}{j_{n}^{m}}\tag{5}$$ where
\begin{align}
j_{n} &= 1728\frac{Q_{n}^{3}}{Q_{n}^{3} - R_{n}^{2}}\tag{6a}\\
b_{n} &= \sqrt{n(1728 - j_{n})}\tag{6b}\\
a_{n} &= \frac{b_{n}}{6}\left\{1 - \frac{Q_{n}}{R_{n}}\left(P_{n} - \frac{6}{\pi\sqrt{n}}\right)\right\}\tag{6c}
\end{align}
We can see that Ramanujan's expression $(1)$ is related to $a_n$ in $(6c)$.

Berndt obtained the value in $(2)$ by using a table of values of $a_n, b_n$. Berndt's book does not indicate the procedure to obtain these numbers.

My question is whether Ramanujan had some inkling of the Chudnovsky series or not. At least the available literature does not give any explicit details regarding this. Also it is not clear how he computed the value of expression $(1)$ for $n=163$. Is there any way to evaluate this without using $a_n, b_n$?

---

It is interesting to observe however that the Chudnovsky series $(5)$ can be obtained using the approach described by Ramanujan in his 1914 paper *Modular Equations and Approximations to $\pi$* ([Link](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram06.html)).